# After webapp was deployed to azurewebsites.net, cannot load xml file from subfolder

Tags: angularjs, azure

I have an AngularJS app.

I have the following folder structure:

```
ROOT
-app
-data
index.html
```

In my service I load bookmarks.xml file, located in data folder:

```
this.$http.get('data/bookmarks.json').then(...)
```

When I run site locally: http://localhost:8080 everything works fine, the file is loaded and rendered.

After I deployed my app to Microsoft Azure, azurewebsites.net, I get this error message where my code loads the bookmarks.json file:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.","status":404,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"data/bookmarks.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}

**Any idea why this is happening?** Looks like it cannot locate the file in data folder. The file is there of course. Tried "/data/bookmarks.json" - no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config, check the  section. This section determines what MIME types your web application is allowed to serve. Make sure that you have the following if you want to be able to download .json files:

```
 <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
 </staticContent>
```

If you don't already have a web.config file (for example, if you're just serving static content), add this as your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is not an asp.net app, only html and javascript

Comment: web.config settings aren't limited to asp.net web apps. Try adding a web.config file with these settings.