# XML File produced in a .NET web app works locally, but the content is empty in production

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7 web app, where I have a controller that results in a `sitemap.xml` file. When I run the application locally, I get an XML file as a result with this content:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"/>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

However, when this is pushed to production (everything is hosted as a web app on Azure), the same endpoint returns nothing. It does recognize the endpoint and looks like this:

[image]

My code to generate this is shown below:

```
    [Route("/sitemap.xml")]
    public async Task SitemapXml()
    {
        var countries = await _countryService.GetBySpecificationAsync(new CountrySpecification()
        {
            Take = int.MaxValue
        });
        
        Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

        using (var xml = XmlWriter.Create(Response.Body, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
        {
            xml.WriteStartDocument();
            xml.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
            xml.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
```

**My question:**
I am completely lost. At first, I thought it was because I didn't add support for static files and this is considered a static file, but I do have:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

In the `Program.cs`.

Any hints on where I should be starting?

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console (f12- develop tools)?

Comment: Unfortunately @thewallrus . No errors: https://prnt.sc/ayQDMe8gwBzs . It also comes from server so doubt it :D

Comment: I would guess is a copy paste imprecision but shouldn't the method return something? Like Task<FileResult> ?

Comment: Is content type xml allowed in the IIS prod?

Comment: I think this may help you [Similar question answered by @Rob Reagan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648294/9799107)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent some time this week wanting to answer this question, and I have time now.

The main issue with your attempt is you are not returning XML results. To do so I suggest using `IActionResult` interface.

Now time to create `sitemap.xml`. IMO there are 2 ways to go from here, either using a library OR writing your own sitemap method.

I will start with a library. For instance, there is a very simple library (NuGet) called `SimpleMvcSitemap.Core`. Install it in your project, and in your controller insert the following code:

```
[Route("/sitemap.xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SitemapXml()
{

    // your await call etc

    List<SitemapNode> nodes = new List<SitemapNode>
    {
        new SitemapNode(Url.Action("Index","Home")),
        new SitemapNode(Url.Action("About","Home")),
        //other nodes
    };

    return new SitemapProvider().CreateSitemap(new SitemapModel(nodes));
}
```

Btw for this test, I created an asp.net MVC .net 7 project.

I have deployed the solution to azure and it works both on local development and on azure. Here is the result:

[image]

If you do want to do it manually, you can do following

```
var listUrls = new List<string>
{
    Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
    Url.Action("About", "Home")
};

return new SitemapResult(listUrls);
```

And here is the implementation:

```
public class SitemapResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _urls;

    public SitemapResult(IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        _urls = urls;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Async = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = false };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(response.Body, settings))
        {
            WriteToXML(writer);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }

    private void WriteToXML(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        // Write the urlset.
        writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
        // url element
        foreach (var item in _urls)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("url");
            // loc
            writer.WriteStartElement("loc");
            writer.WriteValue(item);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

The manual way is also deployed on azure and works, but in the manual way you need to do a lot of work that is already done in a library. To be fair both above outcome is inspired form the question [How to dynamically create a sitemap.xml in .NET core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311264/how-to-dynamically-create-a-sitemap-xml-in-net-core-2).

Answer (score 2):

[from this msdn magazine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/may/extreme-asp-net-dissecting-an-asp-net-mvc-controller): "A controller that returns void will produce an EmptyResult." I assume this holds true also for Task.

So maybe you need to change your return type of your method from `Task` to  `Task<IActionResult>` (or whatever suits you most) and return the content with any of [these availablle methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Then though, I cannot understand why without these mods is currently working locally.